# toHow to use the out parameter when my method has no return value

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn methods in c# and try to make this exercise. Here getting error while using out paratemeters.

```
class Program
{
    static void SearchText(string input, out int stops, out int commas, out int colons)
    {
        int nrOfFullStops = 0;
        int nrOfCommas = 0;
        int SemiColons = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == '.')
            {
                nrOfFullStops++;
            }
            else if (input[i] == ',')
            {
                nrOfCommas++;
            }
            else if (input[i] == ';')
            {
                SemiColons++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? If you don't assign the value to the out variable, the value doesn't get assigned to the out variable.

Comment: The same way you use out parameters when your method has a return value. Does your code not work? I'm having trouble figuring out why you asked this question.

Comment: Perhaps all you need to do is not create new variables inside your `SearchText` method such as `nrOfFullStops`, `nrOfCommas`, etc, and just use your `out` variables inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Remeber that `out` parameters are required to have assigned a value before the method returns.

Comment: rather than use `out` parameters you could instead return a value tuple like `(int stops, int commas, int colons) SearchText(string input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to declare new variables inside `SearchText` method. Do it in following way:

```
static void SearchText(string input, out int stops, out int commas, out int colons)
{
    stops = 0;
    commas = 0;
    colons = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '.')
        {
            stops++;
        }
        else if (input[i] == ',')
        {
            commas++;
        }
        else if (input[i] == ';')
        {
            colons++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked,  so if i understand correctly (string input, out int stops, out int commas, out int colons) if where the variables are declared?

Comment: Yes these are declared there. 2nd thing is that for `out` parameters, need to give some value before leaving the function.

Comment: @Tommy Kindly upvote for the answer as well. It gives oxygen for the contributors.

Comment: got it <3 wasn't able to do it last night since i am new on this site

Answer (score 0):

Use the out parameters in the method instead of creating new ones.